# Unable top delete parse object in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfobject

Im trying to create a function that lets the user delete their post(PFObject) when they tap the trash button. I followed the Parse docs, but I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how I can fix it. Thanks in advance!

heres the code:

```
var currentObject : PFObject?

@IBAction func trashTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let object = currentObject {
        object.deleteInBackground()
    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: is the current object bound with a current viewcontroller? Possibly it's scheduled to delete, but you deallocating currentObject (therefore, object) before it does the job in background?

Comment: You should probably delete this in a block so you know whether it was successfully deleted or not, and only then dismiss the view controller. Delete eventually works better for objects that have been found in queries, as like @OlegShanyuk said, the object might be deallocated before the deletion happens with this method. I'm actually surprised you're not running into internal inconsistency errors.

Comment: @OlegShanyuk the current object is bound to the current VC, however I think you're right that currentObject was getting deallocated, because it did not know what specific object to delete.

Comment: @pbush25 with this setup I didn't run into internal errors, it just did not do anything, but dismiss the VC. However I tried deleting the object in a block and it worked perfectly, thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: @DavidVillegas in the block it might work, as block retains external references. Anyway, this approach is bad design. Better to have an external dependency for the objects list. So, you can safely show/dismiss viewControllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `deleteInBackgroundWithBlock` and then dismiss the view controller inside that block once it has finished, make sure that you call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on the main thread though.

Comment: Thanks deleting the object in a block worked perfectly!